# How to Parse this Json with Json.net?

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have this json:

{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "Email": [
      "The Email field is required."
    ]
  }
}

I want to find the ModelState(if it exists) and then loop through all the errors that re in there.

I can figure out how to do this. I don't want to make a concrete class as the data might change depending on what happens on the sever.

I also can use dynamic as I am on WPF7

```
          JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

            foreach (var j in jsonObj)
            {
               var t = j.Value;

            }
```

this is what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
var modelState = jsonObj["ModelState"];
if (modelState != null)
{
    // The JSON contains a property called ModelState
    // so we can start looping through it:
    foreach (JProperty item in modelState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        foreach (JValue error in item.Values())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }
}
```